# Is this right way to generate the following heavy-tailed distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I'm trying to generate an error distribution which follows a heavy-tailed distribution based on the statement

**: (2) A heavy-tailed distribution, i.e., t-df=2, a t-distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. This distribution has C95=3.61, where C95 is a measure of the distribution tail weight and defined as the ratio of the 95th percentile point to the 75th percentile point**

And this is how I did it.

```
e<-rt(n,c(0.75,0.95),2)
```

I'm not quite sure if I did it correctly. Is this the right way to generate the heavy-tailed distribution mentioned in above statement??

Comment: Using `c(0.75,0.95)` for the `df` parameter makes very little sense. The question itself is unclear. Perhaps you simply want `rt(n,2)`. C95=3.61 seems like a description of a property of this distribution, not something which you have to set.

Comment: Agree with the comment above. You can also try `qt(0.95, df = 2) / qt(0.75, df = 2)`, which seems to agree closely with the property described (although not exactly?)

Comment: The entire question isn't clear. `qt(.95,2)/qt(.75,2)` is 3.57 rather than 3.61 so it isn't true that "this distribution" (seemingly referring to t-dist with 2 degrees of freedom) works as claimed. If the goal is to construct your own distribution with that property, it under-determines the distribution since infinitely many distributions will have the exact ratio of 3.61.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply and sorry for the unclear question. My primary goal is to generate the heavy-tailed distribution. If I want to create a any heavy distribution with sample size 20, should I use rt(n,2) or qt(0.95, df = 2) / qt(0.75, df = 2)? When I checked qt, it seems that it only generates one result.

Comment: @Ryan you should use `rt(20, 2)` to generate 20 samples from the distribution. `qt(0.95, df = 2) / qt(0.75, df = 2)` should have evaluated to 3.61, the value given in the description, and I'm unsure why it doesn't quite match.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!!

Comment: If `x` is a sample generated by `rt(20,2)` then `quantile(x,.95)/quantile(x,.75)` would be a way to *estimate* `qt(.95,2)/qt(.75,2)` and 3.61 is a plausible point-estimate. On the other hand, a quick experiment shows that the ratio of two sample quantiles has a large variance, with most samples of size 20 yielding a ratio that is fairly far from `3.57`.